# What should I call my mathematics thesis's 1st chapter that covers background concepts?

Tags: thesis, masters

I'm preparing my masters thesis in mathematics ([Stochastic Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_calculus)).

My first chapter consists of recalling some concepts like

1. [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).
2. [Clarke's generalized gradient](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-205-00/S0002-9947-1975-0367131-6/S0002-9947-1975-0367131-6.pdf).
3. [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality)
4. [Convex functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).

What is a proper name for this chapter ? I went with **Useful Theorems** but it felt somewhat different than what I'm used to see in books.

Comment: I think this question might be opinion-based. Personally, I think something like "mathematical preliminaries" is suitable.

Comment: @Galen Thanks ! That's a good title for it. It's about optimal control in markovian switching stochastic systems.

Comment: If you call the first chapter "Useful Theorems", what does that suggest about the theorems in the rest of the thesis?

Comment: ["Chapter 1 : I am born"](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/766/766-h/766-h.htm#link2HCH0001).  OK, not original and possibly more detail than needed.  Fallback to "Introduction" which sounds like a good way to start an ...  introduction ?  Or put another way, I think you're overthinking this.

Comment: A journal for which I regularly review would probably want such a section called "Theoretical Background."

Comment: Is this after your Introduction to the problem or is that in the introduction?

Comment: Preliminaries or just Introduction.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but maybe relevant anyway: the theorems you mention seem to be quite a mixed big of results rather than an introduction into one specific topic. It might thus be worthwhile considering to put those result in an appendix rather than in the first chapter. (But needless to say you should double-check with your advisor before doing so.)

Comment: The question is specific to your scientific discipline IMHO. I'd ask it on math.SX maybe.

Comment: How about what you used in the title of your post: "Background concepts"

Comment: Prolegomena to Any Future Convexity

Comment: _"What should I call [...] chapter that covers background concepts?"_ → Why not call it just that: "Background concepts"?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A standard way to go is to write "**Preliminaries**" and give the definitions, notations, theorems, etc. which you use throughout the thesis.

Comment: Or Preliminaries or Introduction or Overview.

Comment: Another common option, along these lines, is “Background”

Comment: @JonCuster I'm in a different field (Physics/Spectroscopy/Semiconductors) but I would expect this to be the chapter after the introduction. E.g. my PhD thesis "Introduction" was 4 pages of scene-setting with no equations or figures; that was followed by "Theoretical Background" - 40 pages with plenty of maths and diagrams.  I'd expect both chapters to be shorter in a Master's thesis of course.

Comment: Preliminaries, Introduction, or Overview are all fine, depending on contents. // Establish notation. State theorems you will use, but without proof (unless method of proof is closely related the main part of the thesis). This chapter will probably not be repeated in any related papers you'll submit. // Start 2nd chapter with new material in a form that will be easy to condense for publication. (Important elements of proofs in the main part of the chapter (details in notes at end). You are not writing a textbook, but motivating, stating, proving new things.

Comment: It's not really the preliminaries of OP's work, those are very-well-established and very-widely-applicable definitions and results.

Comment: @einpoklum I always interpreted "Preliminaries" as "read the things given in this chapter to follow the rest of the manuscript flawlessly"

Answer (score 13):

A somewhat standard structure would be:

1. Introduction - explain what are you trying to accomplish and why it is important
2. Background and related work - briefly explain all key concepts that the reader needs to know to understand your thesis

..followed by methods/proofs/results/analysis/discussion

Answer (score 4):

It may be worthwhile to separate to some extent two sorts of "background". One sort is the background and context needed to understand what you've done, and why you'd want to do it, and why it's progress... The other sort (obviously with overlap), is the background to understand the *guts/proofs/...* of your work.

It is often a mistake to combine the two... somehow in the mistaken belief that perfect logical order is necessary... or something.

So one could have "context/background", as well as "technical prerequisites"... Some readers might appreciate your making the distinction.

... and my joke-analogue is that to explain to someone why an automatic transmission may be better than a manual, and what's involved, ... *FIRST* say "ok, so you know about the Carnot cycle?" ...